# Jetty (9.2.14) GZipFilter Vs GzipHandler

Tags: servlet-filters, jetty-9

Jetty(9.2.14) GZipFilter appends --gzip to ETag value. Where as when GzipHandler is configured, the --gzip is not appended. The Etag value (everything within quotes) is opaque. Is there a reason, why it has to be two different ways within same version of Jetty?